# Any place to get simple planning problems and datasets?

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence

I am implementing a timetabling application in the Drools Planner application. They have included:

1. N queens
2. allocating computer processes into n computers with constrained resources
3. Allocating beds for patients, each bed having special requirements
4. Allocating students for examinations

and so on.

---

I want to **practice simple planning problems** like #1 and #2 to hone my Drools Planner skills. I prefer state problems over path problems.

What are simple enough planning problems who have obvious feasible solutions?

Is there any online resource to get such problems and problem datasets?

Comment: One problem would be solving 4*4 and 9*9 sudoku.

Comment: You're sure you want planning problems instead of constraint satisfaction/maximization problems?

Comment: I care more for feasibility than optimality for these trial problems

Comment: Another set: http://eclipseclp.org/examples/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer you may check [datasets for machine learning research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_datasets_for_machine_learning_research). The list contains datasets growing in size that you may use for different things including planning problems.

[project euler](https://projecteuler.net/) and [eclipseclp](http://eclipseclp.org/examples/index.html/) are also nice resources.